# I want to dynamically change the parent and child div's height based on the window resize using angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Having two div of `col-6`, inside each div, I am having multiple div's.

If I resize my window using scroll I am getting empty space below each div.

I need the increase the height of the div's based on window size also need to change for inside div's height in my `.ts` file angular.

I tried using @Hostistner but only the outer div height is changing

Comment: Use css grid to layout divs inside each col-6. If you post the layout you want and add `css` tag to the question you will get some `css` based suggestions. Or grab the children using `@ViewChild` or `@ViewChildren` and change their height along with changing parent height.

Comment: Can  you plz tell me how to change both the height using @ViewChild

Comment: maybe you can make use of css vh (view-height) units.
Look: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

set parent divs to 100vh, so they are always in full height, no matter what size the window is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make all child's height as 100% using css. or try Gridster component it will make those layout easily 
https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/